# Is there any downside to using the 64-bit version, assuming I never distribute my compiled scripts to 32-bit computers?

Tags: windows-8.1, autohotkey

I'm installing AutoHotKey. I am at this screen:

[image]

I am running windows 8.1 x64. I'm a bit confused about the description under `Unicode 64-bit`

> Faster, but compiled scripts won't run on 32-bit systems

Does this mean that scripts made on a 32-bit system will not work on my computer? Is there *any* downside to using the 64-bit version, assuming I never distribute my compiled scripts to 32-bit computers?

Comment: Your title will get this question closed.

Comment: @Xavierjazz Just wondering, why? Either way, I updated the title. Thanks.

Comment: Your initial title was asking for opinions.

Comment: Didn't mean it like that. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: When I read the body of your question, that's what I thought. Hence my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. I doubt there's any autohotkey script that *needs* the extra memory 64 bit will give you, nor would there be any drawback outside not being able to run scripts you wrote on a 32 bit system.

The scripts themselves should be architecture independant - *compiled* scripts as exes on the other hand would have issues 32 bit compiled AHK scripts will work on a 64bit system, but not vice versa (since 64 bit has backward compatibility to 32 bit).

If you need to *share* scripts with someone who dosen't have AHK, it matters. If you need to share a script with someone who has ahk on 32 bit, give him the source-code to the script and let him run it himself. Practically though, I don't see a massive different here.